# PHP post does not work when data contains a space

Tags: php, forms, post

I've been developing a sport selection system where choose sports and have run into a problem where sports with spaces cannot be deleted.

I've tracked this issue down to the post form, as the script that is meant to pick up the form doesn't when it contains a space. I've done extensive googling on this issue but haven't come up with anything, as all the other similar issues are with improperly configured forms.

Here is the current code:

Form code:

```
<!--Remove Sport-->
<form action="" id="RecSportRemoveForm" method="POST">

<p>Remove Sport</p>
<?php
$sportFile = "recSport.data";
$sportOptionsArray = unserialize(file_get_contents($sportFile));

$sportLength = count($sportOptionsArray);

for($i = 0; $i < $sportLength; $i++) {
    echo ("<input type='checkbox' name=$sportOptionsArray[$i] value=$sportOptionsArray[$i]>$sportOptionsArray[$i]<br>");
}
echo ("<br><button type='submit'>Remove</button> <br>");

?>
</form>
```

Recieve code:(To clarify, I'm filtering and rearranging the keys in another place so that's not an issue)

```
      <!--Checks Remove Sport-->
      <?php
      $sportFile = "recSport.data";
      $sportOptionsArray = unserialize(file_get_contents($sportFile));


       $sportLength = count($sportOptionsArray);

       for($i = 0; $i < $sportLength; $i++) {

           if (isset($_POST[$sportOptionsArray[$i]]) == TRUE){
               $removeSport = $_POST[$sportOptionsArray[$i]];

               $key = array_search($removeSport, $sportOptionsArray);
               unset($sportOptionsArray[$key]);
               echo ($sportOptionsArray[$key]);

               file_put_contents($sportFile, serialize($sportOptionsArray));

               echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Remove');</script>";
               echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert($removeSport);</script>";

               echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content=0;URL=adminDashboard.php>";
           }
       }

      //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Remove');</script>";
      //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert($removeSport);</script>";
   ?>
```

Any help or insight would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Array keys cannot have spaces in them. You need to update your code to remove those spaces or otherwise deal with them. But as long as those values have spaces you can use them as an array key.

Comment: Really? that's weird as the code works perfectly when pushing them onto the array but only experiences issues when deleting. And it doesn't seem to be an issue with the array itself, more the parsing of the form data.

Comment: Is the space being converted to %20?

Comment: No, I'm simply taking the input, storing it, then processing it as is.

Comment: Surround your values for the checkboxes with quotes as in `echo ("<input type='checkbox' name=$sportOptionsArray[$i] value='$sportOptionsArray[$i]>$sportOptionsArray[$i]'<br>");`

Comment: I tried that and several variations of that but it only seems to add quotes around the display or do nothing. Weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up tracking the problem down to how I was posting the data. Essentially, PHP can't post or at least doesn't deal very well with posting names attributes with spaces.

I changed my code slightly to have a generic name attribute (eg. recSport1, recSport2) and kept the data in quotes as Dave pointed out, which solved the problem.

Thanks for all the help guys, it was very much appreciated!